# Share from my webpage to show 'via' appname

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

I am using the following javascript for loading fb icon
`(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id))
        return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));`

`<span class="fb-share-button" data-href="${url}" data-type="icon"></span>`

When the page is shared i need to show via (site_name).
How is this possible. I have a app id too.

Thanks.